# Kafka streams app stuck in IO Wait

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have stream topology that reads from 2 topics, repartitions them and then joins them using a joinWindow of 2 days.

My question is that the kafka streams state store seems to be causing reads and writes of very very small files causing my stream threads to be stuck in IO Wait and due to this my performance is really lagging.

Any performance suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SSD disk, or?

Longer comment - as Kafka is programmed to be robust, it is very IO intensive, as every message is stored on the disk.

BTW, what in numbers means for you "is lagging"? 
About what troughput are you talking?

Comment: Already using SSD, I am looking at a lag of half a million, over around 2 million log size

Comment: 0.5 - 2.0 mio of what? Messages, bytes?

Comment: messages, not bytes

Comment: OK. Very concrete. What clusted do you have? What OS do you have? What means lagging - how much time it costs? 
Check with any JMX monitor, what is your throughput in Bytes per seconds and in the same time check CPU, Memory and IO throughput.

Comment: Shortly - I mean, when you are sending millions of messages (per???) it means you need dedicated cluster, as Kafka do not store data windows of 2 days in regular memory.